# how to update the output on the rising edge of the clock in structural VHDL code?

Tags: vhdl

I have this very simple 16-bit and gate written in structural form in VHDL:
The files are uploaded [here](https://files.fm/u/hkh5kytn).

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity and_16bit is
  Port (
        A   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        B   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        Clk : in   STD_LOGIC;
        --Rst : in   STD_LOGIC;
        C   : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) );
end and_16bit;

architecture Behavioral of and_16bit is
component and_1bit is
  Port (
        A   : in std_logic;
        B   : in std_logic;
        C   : out std_logic );
end component;

signal s : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

begin
            ands: for i in 15 downto 0 generate
            and_1bit_x: and_1bit port map (A => A(i), B => B(i), C => s(i));
            end generate;
process(Clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(Clk) then
             C <= s;                     
        end if;
        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

In order to update the output in the rising edge of the clock, I have defined this "s" signal. I wonder if this is the correct way to update the output in structural VHDL codes? what should I do to scape the unknown output for the first output?

Any comments will be a great help.

Comment: That should work perfectly well.

Comment: That's a Register Transfer Level (RTL) construct that both simulates and synthesizes. A structural representation would devolve the C register into master-slave flip flops comprised of individual gates. There isn't a lot of call for flip flops comprised of gates (transistors, resistors, diodes,...). The source for info on synthesis eligible constructs in HDL would be a synthesis vendor's documentation or the now witthdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (typically a subset of what a vendor will accept).

Comment: "what should I do to scape the unknown output for the first output?". Initialize `s`. I.e. `signal s : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to put the sequential process into a submodule and instantiate it in the top-level (`and_16bit`). Then your top-level will be more structural.

You can have one instance for each bit as you did for `and_1bit`.

For example, this module is a 1-bit register.

```
entity dff_1bit is
    Port (
        D   : in  std_logic;
        Clk : in  std_logic;
        Q   : out std_logic );
end dff_1bit;

architecture Behavioral of dff_1bit is
begin

process(Clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(Clk) then
             Q <= D;                     
        end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Then you can instantiate it in `and_16bit`, inside the same `generate` block.

```
dff_1bit_x: dff_1bit port map (D => s(i), Clk => Clk, Q => C(i));
```

Comment: This way the delay in the waveform of the top-level file gets too big!

Comment: @syzd This code should have the same delay (1 clock cycle) with yours.

Comment: @ahmadeus I checked, it at least doubles

Comment: @syzd Your testbench has a race condition. You can try to put a small delay (e.g. 1 ps) at the beginning of stimulus. Then both codes should behave similarly.